# QT / c++ best way to call a method of parent

Tags: c++, qt, callback, slot, qt-signals

I need to control file I/O using a method (called write) in class A.  A then instantes another class B (not based on A), which needs to write to the file, by calling A.write().

What is the best way to achieve this?

Should I pass the Class.functionname (A.write) as a parameter to B.sometfunction for callback?

Should I make A.write a slot, and allow B to emit a signal?

Is there a better way?  (I'm using QT 5 with C++ )

---

Ok, some more info to help explain:
A is a collection of threads, each being a TcpSocket (console session from client)
B is my logger class, and is a singleton pattern.
A threads sometimes have to log a message to a file, which B formats and writes to the file using a mutex.
These same (formatted) messages should be written to the console (unique socket per A thread, so cannot be a static method).
So A.something calls B.write (to file), and then B.write needs to call A.write (to console).

Comment: It's a curious design when a class represents both a writable object and an object factory... What is the problem you're trying to solve? What do the classes A and B do?

Comment: B is a singleton class called "LOGGER" which logs to a file.  There are many A threads, which must also send the logged message to a socket, so B.write actually calls A.Write too.  I thought of passing the TCP socket to from A to B but not sure that's ideal either

Answer (score 3):

Make A.write() public and give a pointer of A to B or use a signal/slot connection and in B just use emit mysignal(data); which is connected to the slot A.write()...

Answer (score 1):

use a signal/slot connection mechanism to connect `B` signal `write()` to public `A` slot `doWrite()`. Alternatively make `A::write()` just public `static` method and call it from `B` just

```
void B::write() {
    A::write();
    //...
}
```

or simply pass a pointer or reference to `A` to your object of class `B` and call public method through this pointer/reference.

```
void B::write(A& a) {
    a.write();
    //...
}
```

As a side note please reconsider however your design. I am sure you do feel by yourself something is not correct here. Usually this is an instance of `B` that is created in `A` (is a member of `A`) that do the job.

```
class A{
  B b;
  void write(){
    B.write();  // clear
  }
};
```

In your approach `A` creates an object which calls back a parent to do the job.

```
class A{
  B b;
  void foo(){
    B.write(
    // hey hey, I want A.write() come back!  -> confusing oOO
   );
  }
};
```

Comment: I agree that my gut is telling my something isn't quite right with my design, so I added more info above.  You'll see that your first option (static) doesn't work in this case because of multiple A threads each with different socket.  Your second option I like.  Is there a better/right way to do this?